# Set DisableFullScreenOptimization application compatibility flags with Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

My Application needs a "Disable Fullscreen Optimization" in app properties to be checked in order to work.

```
[Registry]
Root: "HKCU"; \
   Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"; \
   ValueType: String; ValueName: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \   
   ValueData: "RUNASADMIN"; Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; \
   MinVersion: 0,6.1
```

Usually I can just simply add `WINXPSP2` in value data parameter if I want to make the app work with Windows XP Service Pack 2 Compatibility, but I just cant find the value if I want the app to run with "Disable Fullscreen Optimization" to be checked.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly, but it exists an option `DISABLEDXMAXIMIZEDWINDOWEDMODE`which may be do the desired thing.

So your new line wold look like this:

```
[Registry] \
Root: "HKCU"; \
    Subkey: "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers\"; \
    ValueType: String; ValueName: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    ValueData: "RUNASADMIN DISABLEDXMAXIMIZEDWINDOWEDMODE"; \
    Flags: uninsdeletekeyifempty uninsdeletevalue; MinVersion: 0,6.1
```

It is possible to set more than one flag in this registry entry.

I found this information on this site:
[How to Change Compatibility Mode Settings for Apps in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/15523-change-compatibility-mode-settings-apps-windows-10-a.html)

On this page a lot of options are described usable in the registry. They are almost at the bottom of the page. If this is not the correct one, perhaps an other one is suitable.